# How do I tell if a PyPI package is pure python or not?

Tags: python, pypi, python-packaging

Is this information published anywhere?

Interested because, in maintaining a conda env, i'd like to install pure python things with pip and other stuff (eg with C deps) with conda.

Comment: But why? Why not just use `conda` for both?

Comment: "*…install pure python things with pip and other stuff (eg with C deps) with conda.*" I'm not sure it's possible. There're pure-python packages that have non-pure dependencies, so `pip install` would bring non-pure packages anyway.

Comment: You can maybe check on PyPI if a project has a `none-any` wheel or not. If it has, then it is likely to be pure Python, I think, I am not sure. -- Anyway, what you are trying to do seems strange to me.

Comment: @phd good point about dependencies

Comment: to give more context on why PyPI - sometimes i find that conda is unnecessarily strict. eg,(1) no osx arm64 compatible candidate, even if it's pure python (2) no python 3.10 compatible candidate yet or (3) conda / conda-forge doesn't have the latest version of something. so i like to go to pypi when i can. hence this question.

Comment: Also, a package might publish extensions for some platform and be a pure python package for others, so the question is "is the package that would be installed on my platform a pure one?"